# Having trouble with continue/breaks in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, break, continue

So I'm currently a novice programmer writing in javascript, and I'm having trouble understand why my continue/break statements aren't working in my code. I appreciate any help, thanks!

```
document.getElementById("start").onclick = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        var x = Math.random();
        x = 6*x;
        x = Math.floor(x);

        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = myArray[x];
        document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Enter";   
        document.getElementById("start").onclick=function(){
            if (document.getElementById("text").value==aArray[x]){
                document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "You are correct!";
                countPoints++;
                document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = countPoints;
                document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Next";
                document.getElementById("start").onclick = function(){
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "Wrong! Gameover!";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your break/continue are inside child functions. break/continue only apply to loops at the SAME code level, but since you're executing them inside sub-functions where there are no loops, there's nothing to break/continue, and they're effectively "do nothing" statements.

in more detail:

```
document.getElementBy("start").onclick = function()  {.... break; ...}
```

only DEFINES a function which contains a break. The function will not execute until the `start` element is clicked on, at which time your `for` loop isn't even running anymore.

It's like putting a "meet me for lunch on dec 10th" note inside a christmas present, and then wondering why no one showed up on the 10th - well, they didn't get the note until the 25th.

Comment: Your more detail clarification is incorrect. The script itself will not execute because of an illegal break statement. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement`

Comment: true enough on that... either way, where the break/continue are, there's no loops, so nothing to break/continue out of.

Comment: That is true. I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding here for the OP with how events are handled and assigned.